# Limiting the search widget results to a country in ArcGIS JS API 4.9

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using the Search widget in the 4.9 version of the javascript API. Can I limit the results to a given country when using the default geocoding service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the locator source to the Search widget (in addition to using the default). So if you create a locator source, and define the world geocode service, it'll accept
**countryCode** as a property: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Search-LocatorSearchSource.html

Below I've added Locator, and done 2 things: 1) Created a new source to the world geocoder, setting the countryCode and 2) turned off the default search source (which is the world geocoder) with the **includeDefaultSources** property. If you dont turn it off, the user needs to use the drop down to use your locator.

```
 "esri/tasks/Locator"  >>  Locator

  var searchWidget = new Search({
    sources: [{
      locator: new Locator({ url: "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"}),
      countryCode:"CA",
      singleLineFieldName: "SingleLine",
      name: "Custom Geocoding Service",
      localSearchOptions: {
        minScale: 300000,
        distance: 50000
      },
      placeholder: "Search Canada",
      maxResults: 3,
      maxSuggestions: 6,
      suggestionsEnabled: true,
      minSuggestCharacters: 0
  }],
    view: view,
    includeDefaultSources: false
  });

  // Add the search widget to the top right corner of the view
  view.ui.add(searchWidget, {
    position: "top-right"
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! `countryCode` was what I was looking for. Is there an option for county as well?

Comment: The world geocoder certainly looks to support more filtering: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-category-filtering.htm  --although I'm not certain you can wire up the Search > Locator definition any more fine grain than "country". Maybe worth a try...