# Limiting search result to country using ArcGIS API for JavaScript integrated with Angular

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, angularjs

I want to restrict my search results to a specific country (NZ) with [ArcGIS Javascript/Angular](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/angular/) API. I am using Angular for this project:

**mygis.component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
await loadCss('https://js.arcgis.com/4.9/esri/css/main.css');
const [WebMap, MapView, _, Search, Locator] = await loadModules([
  'esri/Map',
  'esri/views/MapView',
  'esri/WebMap',
  'esri/widgets/Search',
  'esri/tasks/Locator'
])
// create a Map loaded from a webmap
const webMap = new WebMap({
  basemap: 'hybrid',
  portalItem: { // autocasts as new PortalItem()
    id: "f2e9b762544945f390ca4ac3671cfa72"
  }
});

const search = new Search({
  mapView: MapView,
  includeDefaultSources: false,
  sources: [{
    locator: new Locator({ url:"https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"}),
    CountryCode: "NZ"}],
    name: "Geocode",
});

const mapView = new MapView({
      container: this.mapView,
      center: [175.1278, -36.7074],
      zoom: 9,
      map: webMap,
    });

mapView.ui.add(search, "top-right");
  
  }
}
```

I have created a stackblitz sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/arcgis-sample-kkdnjc?file=src/app/mygis/mygis.component.ts) but I get world wide results. Very similar to [Limiting the search widget results to a country in ArcGIS JS API 4.9](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297918).

Answer (score 1):

You just have a small typo in your code - you have `CountryCode` (first capital C), instead of `countryCode`

```
const search = new Search({
  mapView: MapView,
  includeDefaultSources: false,
  sources: [{
    locator: new Locator({ url:"https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"}),
    countryCode: "NZ"}],
    name: "Geocode",
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I will test this out.